# Cannot run pdo_sqlite on Ubuntu 20.04 with PHP 7.4

Tags: php, 20.04

I'm trying to install and run PDO for sqlite3 on Ubuntu 20.04 with PHP 7.4 and I can't figure out what I'm not doing right. I installed sqlite3 and php-common and uncoment this lines in php.ini:

```
extension=pdo_sqlite
extension=sqlite3
```

When run php, i receive following result:

```
php -i | grep sqlite
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlite' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_sqlite (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_sqlite: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_sqlite.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_sqlite.so: undefined symbol: php_pdo_unregister_driver)) in Unknown on line 0
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_sqlite.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sqlite3.ini,
sqlite3
sqlite3.defensive => 1 => 1
sqlite3.extension_dir => no value => no value
```

This is very strange to me because the file */usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_sqlite.so* exists.
I also tested PHP7.3 and PHP7.2 and the result was the same. Switch between different versions of PHP with:

```
update-alternatives --config php
```

Answer (score 2):

please install sqlite for your php version,
for php7.4 follow below command
**sudo apt install php7.4-sqlite3**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04, too, and solved it by:

1. Commenting back the two extensions in php.ini
2. Installing php-sqlite3

I think uncommenting the extension lines in php.ini directly results in the extensions loading twice causing this issue.