# PHP 7.4 Warning: Unable to load dynamic library 'sqlsrv.so' and 'pdo_sqlsrv.so'

Tags: server, apache2, php, sql

After installing the sql server, I tried to install the php drivers, sqlsrv and pdo_sqlsrv php extensions, following these commands:

```
sudo pecl install sqlsrv
sudo pecl install pdo_sqlsrv
sudo su
printf "; priority=20\nextension=sqlsrv.so\n" > /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/sqlsrv.ini
printf "; priority=30\nextension=pdo_sqlsrv.so\n" > /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/pdo_sqlsrv.ini
exit
sudo phpenmod -v 7.4 sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv
```

But I am getting this PHP Warning:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sqlsrv.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/sqlsrv.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/sqlsrv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20190902/sqlsrv.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/sqlsrv.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlsrv.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_sqlsrv.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_sqlsrv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
```

And then when I try to migrate my database using the sql server throws an error saying that can`t find sql driver.

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : could not find driver (SQL: select * from sysobjects where type = 'U' and name = migrations)
```

Does anyone have any idea how to solve? I use Ubuntu 18.04 and PHP version 7.4.10

Comment: Are those two extensions also in your php.ini directly?  It looks like double listing might be a problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240508/cannot-run-pdo-sqlite-on-ubuntu-20-04-with-php-7-4

Answer (score 10):

Finally got it to work. You need to set the cli version to 7.4

```
sudo apt install php7.4-dev
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.4
sudo update-alternatives --set php-config /usr/bin/php-config7.4
sudo update-alternatives --set phpize /usr/bin/phpize7.4
sudo pecl install -f sqlsrv
sudo pecl install -f pdo_sqlsrv
sudo phpenmod -v 7.4 sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Russell, this saved me so much time after I've been struggling for days.  thanks a lot

Comment: It worked for me on ubuntu 20.04 with php 7.4

Comment: Simplest solution! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, this helped fix the same issue for me with php 8.0 and 8.2 being on the same box!

Answer (score 2):

In case someone is wondering still relevant for Php 8.2

```
sudo apt install php8.2-dev
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php8.2
sudo update-alternatives --set php-config /usr/bin/php-config8.2
sudo update-alternatives --set phpize /usr/bin/phpize8.2
sudo pecl install -f sqlsrv
sudo pecl install -f pdo_sqlsrv
sudo phpenmod -v 8.2 sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

This perfectly worked in ubuntu 18.04

```
sudo apt install php7.4-dev
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.4
sudo update-alternatives --set php-config /usr/bin/php-config7.4
sudo update-alternatives --set phpize /usr/bin/phpize7.4
sudo pecl install -f sqlsrv
sudo pecl install -f pdo_sqlsrv
sudo bash -c "echo extension=sqlsrv.so > /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/sqlsrv.ini"
sudo ln -s /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/sqlsrv.ini /etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/sqlsrv.ini
sudo ln -s /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/sqlsrv.ini /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/sqlsrv.ini
sudo bash -c "echo extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so > /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/pdo_sqlsrv.ini"
sudo ln -s /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/pdo_sqlsrv.ini /etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/pdo_sqlsrv.ini
sudo ln -s /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/pdo_sqlsrv.ini /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/pdo_sqlsrv.ini
sudo phpenmod -v 7.4 sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same issue by installing the **libodbcinst.so.2** library.

```
apt-get install unixodbc
```

Then, added "extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so" and "extension=sqlsrv.so" to the php.ini configuration file.

you can use **php -i | grep ini** to find the configuration file location.

Restart php-fpm.